# Good GPS navigation app for iPhone with downloadable OFFLINE maps?

Tags: gps, imagery, offline, navigation, iphone

I am looking for a good GPS navigation app for my iPhone that will work away from wifi and cell coverage (GPS only) and thus allow me to download offline maps.

Paid app is OK.

**Must Have features:**

Best possibly quality vector and imagery maps for (Non-urban, rural Canada, NW Ontario, filesize does not matter).

Ability to save/organize waypoints, tracks, areas (enter/edit names).

Ability to import KML/KMZ, Shapefile, GPX via email, Google Drive or Dropbox

Ability to export KML/KMZ, Shapefile, GPX to file, email, Google Drive or Dropbox

Track statistics; profile, average elevation, pace, speed, etc.

**Nice to have features:**

UPLOAD MY OWN IMAGERY and custom maps!

Synchronize with Google Drive / Dropbox

Auto export location on interval to Google Drive / Dropbox

I am currently using a free version of GPS Tracks which is not bad but I don't know what is the quality/coverage of the available "paid" offline maps:

GPS Tracks offers these services for offline download:

Mapbox Street Maps (?)
Mapbox Satellite Maps (?)
Mapbox Terrain Maps (?)
Mapquest Street Maps (mediocre in my area)
MapQuest Satellite Maps (high res only in urban areas)
CalTopo Maps (U.S. only)

Comment: Here Maps does 90% what you are asking https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/here-offline-navigation-maps/id955837609?mt=8

Comment: In this [related question for Android](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/7567/) someone mentions an app called xGPS as being for iphone and may do some or all of what you want.

Answer (score 0):

[Guru Maps](https://gurumaps.app/), formerly known as Galileo, will do this well, on iOS or Android.

Some of what is listed above is available in the free app, some requires a subscription.

(I realize this is a >4 year old question, but it popped up for me and is still relevant today. I'm not affiliated with Guru except that it is a regular part of my in-the-field workflow.)